# Best method to find the extrema points of a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm looking for a method to find the maximum and minimum values of a 2D integer array in C++. I'm aware of the `std::max_element()` and `std::min_element()`, but they only seem to work for one dimensional arrays.

The 2D array could be declared and initialized by:

```
int temp[5][5];

for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        temp[x][y] = some_random_number;
    }
}
```

A simple method could be to do something like:

```
int min = high_number;
int max = low_number;

for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        if(temp[x][y] < min)
        {
            min = temp[x][y];
        }
        if(temp[x][y] > max)
        {
            max = temp[x][y];
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem very optimized. Is anyone able to give some advice or propose a better idea?

Comment: Don't optimise, do a simple and dumb implementation that is easy to debug. Optimize when this becomes a bottleneck when profiling.

Comment: There is no better solution (There might be some sugar sparing some typing)

Comment: The only way you could optimize finding the min/max is to keep your array sorted by row or column.  It would add complexity to your insertion/populating the array, but you could find min/max in O(n) where n is the number of rows or columns.

Comment: @DieterLücking:`std::minmax_element` has a less factor complexity than `std::min_element` + `std::max_element`. `3/2` vs `2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` like this:

```
int arr[2][2] = {{434, 43}, {9826, 2}};
auto pair = std::minmax_element(&arr[0][0], &arr[0][0] + 4);
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eef121abe38660d)</kbd>

where `4` is the total number of elements.

Notice that for readability the above solution uses `operator&` to get the address to the beginning of the array, but `std::addressof` is recommended because `operator&` could be overloaded.

If you want you can also declare helper functions for the equivalent bidimensional array `begin` and `end` functions:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
auto bi_begin(T (&arr)[N][M]) {
    return std::addressof(arr[0][0]);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
auto bi_end(T (&arr)[N][M]) {
    return bi_begin(arr) + N * M;
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84906862bddf0257)</kbd>

I've intentionally avoided the names `begin` and `end` because it could generate infinite discussions here.

---

Overall, I would recommend defining a `matrix` type which is implemented as a `std::array` of `M * N` elements, and then provide proper `begin` and `end` member functions, which can then be used with any standard algorithm.

Comment: You may even use `std::minmax_element`

Comment: Worth mentioning, I think - this works with an *array of arrays*, as is shown here and in the question.  But not with the similar-acting *array of pointers to arrays*.

Answer (score 4):

If there are no other constraints on the contents of your array/matrix, you cannot do better than looking at each element. That means that your solution is actually an optimal solution in terms of asymptotic running time.

I would also argue that it is good in terms of readability, but some might find this easier to read (since it's shorter):

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
   for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
   {
      min = std::min(temp[x][y], min);
      max = std::max(temp[x][y], max);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the type of the array to

```
constexpr int n = 5;
constexpr int m = 7;
std::array<int,n*m> ar;
```

and access like

```
ar[i*n + j]
```

then you simply write

```
auto min = std::min_element(ar.begin(), ar.end());
auto max = std::max_element(ar.begin(), ar.end());
```

Comment: You may even use `std::minmax_element`

Answer (score 0):

Just by changing your structure, you can maybe use iterator

```
int main()
{
    int c_array[5] = {};
    std::array<int, 5> cpp_array = {};
    std::vector<int> cpp_dynarray(5);

    auto c_array_begin = std::begin(c_array); // = c_array + 0
    auto c_array_end = std::end(c_array);     // = c_array + 5

    auto cpp_array_begin = std::begin(cpp_array); // = cpp_array.begin()
    auto cpp_array_end = std::end(cpp_array);     // = cpp_array.end()

    auto cpp_dynarray_begin = std::begin(cpp_dynarray); // = cpp_dynarray.begin()
    auto cpp_dynarray_end = std::end(cpp_dynarray);     // = cpp_dynarray.end()
}
```

And use loop like :

```
mypointer = arr;
for(auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it) {
        min = std::min(*mypointer, min)
        max = std::max(*mypointer, max)
}
```